# Is it possible to have WPF/SL4 perform operations on a property binded to another control?

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, converters

Using SilverLight, one can bind the value of a control to a property from a datacontext. That's fine.

It is possible to use StringFormat along with the binding declaration to format the value. Again, that's cool!

However, I can't find a way to have the binding with some operation done to it before it gets displayed. I know I can code an IConverter but I was looking for something purely in XAML if that exists. I could also add a property to the class that returns the data in the correct way, but still what would happen if you don't have the source of the class?

For example, let's say I have this class for my datacontext (properly setup with notification and the like):

```
public class Info
{
    public int SomeValue {...}    // Value from 0 to 15
}
```

I would like to have a binding that would display 45 instead of 15 where the binding would be declared something like {Binding SomeValue, Operation="*3"}

Is there something like this in the .NET world (either from MSoft or OpenSource)?

Comment: whay's wrong with a ValueConverter? for doing a simple multiplication on a value in pure XAML I believe there was a solution with ScaleTransform, can't seem to find a link though...

Comment: Precisely, ValueConverter is great but I need to code it. Not that I don't want to but I don't feel coding multiple value converters when I could use a generic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found [the link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/08e73076-4d88-468b-a402-1e6c9429c5e1) I was talking about.

Still, Charles Petzold also suggest to rather use a ValueConverter, even though some arithmetics is possible in pure XAML